# Need information on Bilinear Maps

Tags: cryptography

I've googled the following URL's and need more simple information regarding Bilinear Maps

Intro to Bilinear Maps -- by Bethencourt and

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_map

Lecture 25: Pairing-Based Cryptography -- MIT course

I would like to know in a simple to understand framework

1) what is a bilinear pairing -- an example would be great
2) how is it useful say in CP-ABE -- ciphertext policy attribute based encryption schema

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

A pairing, in cryptography, is a way to make three-party operations.

Suppose that you have three groups *G<sub>1</sub>*, *G<sub>2</sub>* and *G<sub>3</sub>*, in which [discrete logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm) is hard. Let's note group operation additively (with a '+' sign) in *G<sub>1</sub>* and *G<sub>2</sub>*, and multiplicatively in *G<sub>3</sub>*. A pairing *e* is a function which takes one element of *G<sub>1</sub>* and one element of *G<sub>2</sub>*, and outputs an element of *G<sub>3</sub>*, such that, for all integers *a* and *b*, and all group elements *X<sub>1</sub>* and *Y<sub>1</sub>* (from *G<sub>1</sub>*) and *X<sub>2</sub>* and *Y<sub>2</sub>* (from *G<sub>2</sub>*), you get:

*e(X<sub>1</sub> + X<sub>2</sub>, Y<sub>1</sub>) = e(X<sub>1</sub>, Y<sub>1</sub>) e(X<sub>2</sub>, Y<sub>1</sub>)* (pairing is linear in the first parameter)

*e(X<sub>1</sub>, Y<sub>1</sub> + Y<sub>2</sub>) = e(X<sub>1</sub>, Y<sub>1</sub>) e(X<sub>1</sub>, Y<sub>2</sub>)* (pairing is linear in the second parameter)

*e(aX, bY) = e(X, Y)<sup>ab</sup>* (actually a consequence of the bilinearity explained above)

An example of a very weak pairing is the following: let *p* and *q* be two prime numbers such that *q* divides *p-1*. Let *g* be a multiplicative generator of a sub-group or order *q* modulo *p* (i.e. *g* is not 1, but *g<sup>q</sup> = 1* mod *p*). Define *G<sub>1</sub>* and *G<sub>2</sub>* to be the integers modulo *q*, with addition as group operation. Define *G<sub>3</sub>* to be the subgroup generated by *g*. Then, define *e* as: *e(X, Y) = g<sup>XY</sup>* mod *p*. This gives you a non-degenerate pairing ("non-degenerate" means that the pairing can return values other than 1). But it is useless for cryptography because "discrete logarithm" in *G<sub>1</sub>* and *G<sub>2</sub>* is a matter of a simple modular division, i.e. very easy to compute efficiently (because we used integer addition as group law).

A non-weak pairing can be used for [identity-based cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID-based_cryptography) (where the public key of someone *is* their email address, not some mathematical object linked to the address through a signed certificate -- the point being, precisely, to avoid a [PKI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_infrastructure)). It can also be used for three-party Diffie-Hellman, or more generally protocols which involve three entities at a time (e.g. protocols for "electronic cash" or some voting systems). See [this page](http://crypto.stanford.edu/ibe/) for some details and links.

The currently only known cryptographically strong pairings, but still usable in practice, are based on specially crafted elliptic curves. See [Ben Lynn's PhD dissertation](http://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/thesis.html) for a mathematical introduction, and [PBC](http://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/) for the implementation. An "easy" variant will make *G<sub>1</sub>* and *G<sub>2</sub>* an elliptic curve over a field *GF(p)* (for a prime integer *p*), and *G<sub>3</sub>* will be a multiplicative subgroup of the invertible elements in *GF(p<sup>2</sup>)*. Be warned that it is somewhat higher-level mathematics than "plain" elliptic curves (you have to know how field extensions work).